# Django Admin override UserAmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

I used this admin code, to adjust my

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    list_display = UserAdmin.list_display + ('show_url', 'date_joined')

    def show_url(self, obj):
        return format_html("<a href='{url}'>Link</a>", url=obj.extendeduser.get_link())


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

But the admin just seems to ignore this and displays the old admin page. What could i have missed?

The code is placed in an admin.py of an app I called "main", which is listed in the INSTALLED_APPS list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
    'main',
    ...
]
```

Comment: In which file do you place this code?

Comment: as per @vanadium23's comment, it needs to go in an admin.py that is in an app registered in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py

Answer (score -1):

To create custom user admin pages easier, see: [django-authtools](https://django-authtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: As useful as it may be, this tip is more suited for a comment than a quality answer...